# iOS 11 - Xcode 9.0 Beta 3 error: Use of undeclared identifier 'vabs_s8'

Tags: ios, xcode, ios11, xcode9-beta

Xcode gives me this weird error: **Use of undeclared identifier 'vabs_s8'**

File path: */Applications/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS11.0.sdk/usr/include/simd/common.h*

This file is included by GameKit framework:
GameKit.h => simd.h => vector.h => common.h

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Comment: did you add any third party framework in project ?

Comment: No, it compiles on Xcode 8.3.3 but not on Xcode 9 - beta.

Answer (score 0):

This error is to do with the architecture your targeting. A simple workaround is to place these at the top of common.h file.

`#undef arm64`
`#undef arm`

Answer (score 0):

As you've noticed,gamekit includes **simd/common.h** in which ‘**vabs_s8()**’ function is undeclared.

Naturally, simd/common.h includes simd/base.h -> and -> simd/base.h includes arm_neon.h if **ARM_NEON** is defined. In arm_neon.h we have the declaration of ‘vabs_s8()’ function.

So if vabs_s8 is undeclared means the header is not included which means **__ARM_NEON__** is not defined.

**__ARM_NEON__** is enabled by default if you target armv7/arm64, so this means there might be something wrong with your project settings.

**Solution**: One of our programmers found out that adding "**-mfpu=neon**" in **Other C Flags** fixes this issue.